# CP routes are suddenly prefixed by /web/ directory

Tags: craft4

I've deployed my website for a second time but there is a problem now..

When I navigate through my page, everything works fine apart from one page that fetches a graphQL query, but this returns an error 400.

The main part is when I go to site.com/admin
I get redirected to site.com/web/admin but there is nothing on that page..

And every url in the dashboard has that /web/ extension in the navigation path..

Any ideas how to fix this??

Comment: Did you use a symlink to set the root to /web? In case you didn't you should symlink the served directory to /web

Comment: @Kenneth, no idea what I did but I've got it working. Thanks for your answer!